# Avoid DB calls to reduce memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am new to Linq please help me with my problem.
I am trying to avoid DB calls as it is taking ages to load my page.

### My code:

### I am calculating retailers on weekly basis so that I can get list of retailerId's

```
var weeklyRetailers =
                result.Where(i => i.ManufacturerId == manufacturerRow.Id && i.CountryId == countryRow.Id
                                  && i.CategoryId == categoryRow.Id && i.Date >= localStart && i.Date <= localEnd);
```

### Now I am getting retailer row to access retailer objects from DB

```
 var retailer = _retailerRepository.GetRetailer(weeklyRetailer.RetailerId);
```

### Note

Instead of going to DB for each retailer call which is taking too long if there are too many weeks selection, So I want to avoid Db calls.

### So I tried :

```
var retailersListToIterate = _retailerRepository.GetAllRetailersList();
```

### My repository function

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return a list of retailer row 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Retailer> GetAllRetailersList()
    {
        List<Retailer> a = (from aa in _er.Retailers
                           orderby aa.Description ascending
                           select aa).ToList();
        return a;
    }
```

### Using Linq

```
var retailer = retailersListToIterate.Where(i => i.Id == weeklyRetailer.RetailerId);
```

> But this is not returning me entire Retailer row to access Retailer object.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: So you think that getting all retailers is more efficient than selecting only one? Why??

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes so each time when I want a retailer infomration I dont need to go to DB instead I can use my retailersToInterate object I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of

```
var retailer = retailersListToIterate.Where(i => i.Id == weeklyRetailer.RetailerId);
```

is not a `Retailer` object, this is an `IEnumerable<Retailer>`. Therefore you should check it for length etc. and than use `ElementAt(0)` on your result.

Or write

```
var retailer = retailersListToIterate.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == weeklyRetailer.RetailerId);
```

which will give you exactly one `Retailer` or `null` if retailer `ID` is unknown.

Also if I got you right, you have some multiselect and want to get list of selected retailers in one go to DB. In that case you can create a list with IDs of your retailers and query DB with a conditional clause `where myListOfIds.Contains(i.Id)`. This is safe as long as you don't query more than 4000 retailers or so, coz this will be translated in `SELECT FROM IN(ID1, ID2 ...)` statement in SQL, which has a limitation on the number of elements in the IN clause.

Answer (score 2):

I am having a hunch that you are doing filtering on IEnumerable object. If you are doing DB operation and doing some filtering on the data set, always do filtering on IQueryable object and not on IEnumerable(List) object. Will save you from lot of wasted time. For difference see the link.
[Difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable](http://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/difference-between-ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-in-net-c/)